# Unwanted characters after word in output

Tags: c

I created a program that asks the user for a word and then it arranges the letters in that word in alphabetical order and stores it in another string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  char in[100],out[100],ch;
  int  i,len,j=0;

  //ask user for a word
  printf("Enter a word: ");
  scanf("%s",in);

  //arrange that word in alphabetical order
  for(ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch)
         for(i = 0; i < strlen(in); ++i)
               if(in[i] == ch)
               {
                        out[j] = ch;
                        ++j;
               }

  //print the word
  printf("%s",out);

  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
}
```

The problem is when word is stored in the other string, there are some extra letters or symbols after that word. Can someone please tell me what could be possibly wrong with my code?

Comment: Add a string terminator (`'\0'`) to the end of `out` after filling it.

Comment: Declare and initialize your char array `out` like this: `char out[100]={0};`
Thus string in it will be null terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings are null terminated

Use

`out[j]  ='\0';`

before `printf`

The `%s` specifier searches for a null termination.

In your case it keeps on printing until it finds one, so you get some random symbols.

Also avoid use of `fflush`.

You might want to update your logic to sort uppercase characters too.

You might want to use a sort say [`bubble sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

```
  l=strlen(in);
  for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
  {
        for(j = i + 1; j < l - 1; j++)
            if(in[j-1] > in[j]){
                ch = in[j];
                in[j] = in[j-1];
                in[j-1] = ch;
            }
  }

  printf("Sorted String :%s",in);
```

Comment: As for the sorting: please don't suggest a specific algorithm. Leave that choice up to the OP (as it looks like he/she's still learning C). Also you would do a `strcpy()` to `out` first and rearrange the `out` string instead of working with `in`

Answer (score 4):

You're not [null terminating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) the output string. `printf("%s",out);` will keep outputting characters until it finds 0 (`'\0'`). There are many options to fix this:

1. terminate the output to the current iterator position after the for-loop:

   `out[j] = '\0';`
2. make the output the same length as the input:

   `out[strlen(in)] = '\0';`
3. declare a 0-initialized array:

   `char out[100] = { 0 };`
4. fill the output array with zero's yourself:

   `memset(out, 0; sizeof(out));`
5. ...

As the sorting is concerned, if it's just for learning then it's fine, otherwise you should pick a more efficient [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)